# Search for two alternative version numbers using "grep"

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I have a file `file.txt`

```
c-hcos-49.84.202106221
c-hcos-4.4.9-open
c-hcos-4.9.9-open
```

I want to grep lines that contain either `49` or `4.9` immediately after the string `hcos-`.

I used

```
cat file.txt| grep 'hcos' | grep '4\\.9\\|49'
```

Its showing all lines in output
Actual output

```
c-hcos-49.56.202106221
c-hcos-4.4.9-open
c-hcos-4.9.9-open
```

The expected output is

```
c-hcos-49.84.202106221
c-hcos-4.9.9-open
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Why would you expect a line with a string `4.4.9` to _not_ match a regular expression stating "a string containing `4.9` or `49`"? Btw, since your file contains only single words, what do you need the `awk` call for?

Comment: I removed awk. I want to match 4.9.x and 49.x only not 4.4.9

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your case, you want to find all lines that contain `49.` or `4.9.` immediately after the string `hcos-`. To do so, use

```
grep -E 'hcos-4\.?9\.' file.txt
```

where the `-E` option instructs `grep` to use extended regular expressions syntax. In basic regular expression syntax this would be achieved by:

```
grep 'hcos-4\.\{0,1\}9\.' file.txt
```

You don't need to `cat` a file into `grep` as `grep` can open the files on its own.

Comment: `egrep 'hcos-4\.?9'` would be portable, though not standard (and so probably not future-proof)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I briefly considered mentioning `egrep` but decided against it for the exact reason you stated.

Comment: Yes, `egrep` should not be used in *new* code. And Oracle customers should keep complaining about the sad state of utilities in `/bin` on Solaris to Oracle.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, when we got a new Sun, the first step was `GNU > /usr/local`, as somebody humorously described it. Exactly for the reason you state.

Comment: @AdminBee Thanks it really helped One more question if I just want to grep 4.9 or 49 There can be . or _ or any number at end. How can I do that I tried ```grep -E '4\\.?9'``` But it's again picking up ```4.4.9```

Comment: @user478970 You may want to read up a little on regular expressions (see [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) e.g.). In your case, you could e.g. specify exactly that such a character needs to follow: `4\\.?9[._0-9]` should do.

Answer (score 2):

A general way to solve this is to use alternation:

`grep 'hcos-\(4\.9\|49\)' file.txt`

(The solutions with optional '.' work just for this specific case).